# Why my aniamted GIF is so slow on browsers and mobile?

Tags: css, safari, gif, animated-gif

Why my aniamted GIF is so slow on browsers and mobile? i set my speed at 1/100 in fireworks but on browser is way sloer...how can make a fluid smooth animation to display as a loader? is the compression or some other tricks? using SVG maybe?

i've seen pretty smooth anumation out there so i'm wondering how can be done...

thanks

**update**
this is an example of fluid gif:

http://img-thumb.ffffound.com/static-data/assets/6/7462923e68408973396e8cafd5fccd9b414f73b3_s.gif

Comment: loading speed depends on the dimension, filesize and number of indexed colors.

Answer (score 4):

sounds like i found myself. and it may be a bug of Fireworks CS6 or what not

Basically I was saving with frame-rate at 1/100sec. per state. for soem reason this slow down the gif (maybe overloads the browser)

by saving at 3/100 for each state is enough to have a super fluid animation!